Failed to notify dependency resolution listener, void org.gradle.api.artifacts.Dependency
Failed to notify dependency resolution listener.
'void org.gradle.api.artifacts.DependencySubstitutions$Substitution.with(org.gradle.api.artifacts.component.ComponentSelector)'
I keep getting this error, and I cant for the life of me figure out how to fix it.
My build.gradle
projects/modules.
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

My app\build.gradle
type hereplugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.grzeluu.lookupplant"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        buildFeatures {
            viewBinding true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation("com.example.library:library-a:1.2.3")

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'

    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'

    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:20.0.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:6.2.1'

    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'

    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.5'

    implementation "com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0"
    annotationProcessor "com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0"

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

}

My gradle.wrapper.properties
type heredistributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.9-bin.zip
networkTimeout=10000
validateDistributionUrl=true
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists


I've scrolled through the entire internett at this point it feels like, even used the Gemini inside Android Studio, but to no help.

There looks to be random text at the start of each of your files you've not removed.
